# OData implementation in Salesforce

Tags: lightning-connect, odata

Salesforce is supporting [OData 2 protocol using](http://www.odata.org/) Lightning Connect, However do we have any information or way on how Data inside Salesforce can be exposed as OData ? These records then can be used by another Salesforce Organization or any other platform. I tried to search documentation however was not able to find any solution on how Data can be exposed as OData protocol?

Comment: Is there any business scenario why you would like to expose SFDC data as OData ?Would like to understand use case as Salesforce provides excellent REST API's

Comment: I dont have any requirement yet, However thinking that if other vendors support OData and SFDC is only consuming it. If OData becomes standard in near future other systems might also want to consume it and as SFDC we should be able to provide them else we would be relying on REST, SOAP endpoints

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce doesn't currently expose data as OData. If you want to access Salesforce data using OData you currently need to rely on a third party solution like one offered by [rssbus](https://www.rssbus.com/odata/salesforce/).  If you want to access Salesforce data exposed by one Salesforce org to another using Lightning Connect, there is currently a pilot for a Salesforce connector which is intended to eventually GA as part of the Lightning Connect SKU.  It uses the standard REST API behind the scenes though, not OData.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is currently no native support for exposing OData from Salesforce. I wouldn't be surprised if this changes in the future though.

Meanwhile, there are several vendors who support exposing SFDC data via OData adapters. I don't know the landscape there very well, but you'd probably want to start with Informatica and CData.